# R- Conditionally extracting data from one file based on data in another file

Tags: r

I have two different timestamp data file with different frequency. I want to extract data from one file (YY: DD: MM HH: MM: SS) based on the timestamp (YY: DD: MM HH:MM:00) of second data file in a range of (+_2 minutes). 
I need to extract data based on each timestamp value of second data.

How I can solve it? Do I need to apply for loop or anything else? I am using xts package and newcomer in R

Comment: Can you also share the desired output and more descriptive logic to populate those values?

Comment: I edited my question again and  put the desire output table also .... However, I really thankful to all for all your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it's hard to solve your problem, but try to adapt this code:

**INPUT**: two data.frames coming from your two files:

```
df1<-data.frame(ts1=c("18: 24: 03 11: 12: 13","18: 24: 03 11: 20: 13","18: 24: 03 11: 21: 33"),b=c(1,2,3))
df2<-data.frame(ts2=c("18: 24: 03 9: 50: 00","18: 24: 03 11: 20: 00"))
df1
                    ts1 b
1 18: 24: 03 11: 12: 13 1
2 18: 24: 03 11: 20: 13 2
3 18: 24: 03 11: 21: 33 3

df2
                        ts2
    1  18: 24: 03 9: 50: 00
    2 18: 24: 03 11: 20: 00
```

A function `f` doing the match with interval dates

```
f<-function(ts,ts2)
{

  out<-(as.POSIXct(ts,format="%y: %d: %m %H: %M: %S")<=as.POSIXct(ts2,format="%y: %d: %m %H: %M: %S")+2*60) & (as.POSIXct(ts,format="%y: %d: %m %H: %M: %S")>=as.POSIXct(ts2,format="%y: %d: %m %H: %M: %S")-2*60)
  return(as.logical(max(out)))
}
```

Your desired **OUTPUT**:

```
df1[unlist(lapply(as.POSIXct(df1$ts1,format="%y: %d: %m %H: %M: %S"),f,ts2=df2$ts2)),]
                    ts1 b
2 18: 24: 03 11: 20: 13 2
3 18: 24: 03 11: 21: 33 3
```

This is obviously just a track to help you in the implementetion of your code

**Update**, with a different timestamp format:

```
Input:
    df1<-data.frame(a=c(2,5,8,2),ts1=c("2017-10-07 16:51:08.000","2017-10-07 16:51:10.000","2017-10-07 16:52:15.000","2017-10-07 16:53:25.000"))
    df2<-data.frame(ts2=c("2017-10-07 16:50:00","2017-10-07 16:51:00","2017-10-07 16:53:00"))
```

Same approach:

```
f<-function(ts,ts2)
 {

   out<-(as.POSIXct(ts)<=as.POSIXct(ts2)+2*60) & (as.POSIXct(ts)>=as.POSIXct(ts2)-2*60)
   return(as.logical(max(out)))
 }
```

Your output:

```
df1[unlist(lapply(as.POSIXct(df1$ts1),f,ts2=df2$ts2)),]
  a                     ts1
1 2 2017-10-07 16:51:08.000
2 5 2017-10-07 16:51:10.000
3 8 2017-10-07 16:52:15.000
4 2 2017-10-07 16:53:25.000
```

Comment: Please find the sample below      Sample_1
              "TIMESTAMP"         "29" "30" "31"
"1" "2017-10-07 16:51:08.000" 3 6 7
"2" "2017-10-07 16:51:10.000" 5 6 6
"3" "2017-10-07 16:52:15.000" 8 80 20
"4" "2017-10-07 16:53:25.000" 2 12 13       

Sample_2
           "TIMESTAMP"         "Max"   "Min
"1" 2017-10-07 16:50:00 11.32 10.95
"2" 2017-10-07 16:51:00 15.76 6.9
"3" 2017-10-07 16:53:00 11.92 11.62

Comment: Thanks Terru , I will try .please find the samples which i put in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks Bro, I will try

Answer (score 0):

for an example,  we have two data table output data and input data.
define a for loop and create a window ( +- 2 min) and at last rbind all data.

here w_low = time-2min w_high = time+2min final = data.table() for (i in 1:nrow(Output)) { t_low <- Output[i,DateTime] - w_low*60 t_high <- Output_Data[i,DateTime] - w_high*60

input_subset <- Input[TIMESTAMP >= t_low & TIMESTAMP < t_high] n= nrow(input_subset)

input_subset[,TIMESTAMP:= difftime(TIMESTAMP, t_low, units = "secs")]

input_subset$output_index <- rep(i,n) final = rbind(OF,input_subset, fill=TRUE)